# jaxb mapping for xml element with prefix of namespace

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

How to annotate in pojo class while mapping it with xml which has a xml element with prefix of namespace like below:

```
<PPS xmlns:oag="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" languageCode="en-US">
  <oag:creationdatetime>2015-01-05T11:48:30</oa:creationdatetime>
</PPS>
```

I have tried as below but the creationdatetime value is coming as null when I try to unmarshal it:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PPS")
public class PPS { 

private String creationdatetime; 

public String getCreationdatetime() {
return creationdatetime;
}

@XmlElement(name="creationdatetime",namespace="oag")
public void setCreationdatetime(String creationdatetime) {
this.creationdatetime = creationdatetime;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace parameter value should be url and not the prefix for @XmlElement(namespace="") :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PPS")
public class PPS { 

private String creationdatetime; 

public String getCreationdatetime() {
return creationdatetime;
}

@XmlElement(name="creationdatetime",namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9")
public void setCreationdatetime(String creationdatetime) {
this.creationdatetime = creationdatetime;
}

}
```